# Explain a MailChimp API error message: The resource 'Campaign_Collection' could not be found

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm upgrading us to the new MailChimp v3 API.

FWIW, we're using [DrewM's PHP library](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api).

When I try to [create a new campaign](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/), I get this cryptic error message from MailChimp:

```
Array (
  [type] => http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/
  [title] => Resource Not Found
  [status] => 404
  [detail] => The resource 'Campaign_Collection' could not be found.
  [instance] =>
)
```

The URL (http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary) is only partially helpful; yes a resource is missing. But *what* is a Campaign_Collection? Is it a Mailchimp list? A Mailchimp folder? Some sort of array-construct I need to use to specify some form of data?

Comment: https://mailchimp.com/contact/

Comment: The MC devs on StackOverflow are more likely to reply quicker than the support guys sitting behind that web form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

If you get the error, the **404** field is the key clue, and the **detail** field is a red herring.

This is the sort of error you get if you misspell an endpoint. For example:

```
$mailer = new MailChimp('****YOUR API KEY****');
$response = $mailer->get('/xyzzy');

// Produces this:
$response = [
     "type" => "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
     "title" => "Resource Not Found",
     "status" => 404,
     "detail" => "The resource 'Xyzzy_Collection' could not be found.",
     "instance" => "",
   ]
>>>
```

Me, I had left off an 's' off the Campaigns endpoint.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it is too lat but thought it could be helpful to some other folks.
Usually Mailchimp returns "***The requested resource could not be found.***" without telling if it is due to your list id or method etc..

Make sure you are using the correct list id. It is **NOT** the one you see on your URL. From the top menu, you need to go to **`Audience`** and select "**`All Contacts`**"

[image]

Then you need to go:

```
Audience -> Settings -> Audience Name and defaults
```

[image]

Then on the right column you will see "Audience ID" with a some weird, meaningless explanation as:

"**Some plugins and integrations may request your Audience ID. Typically, this is what they want: abcd1234xxx.**"

That is the "*listID*" you need!

[image]

PS: If it is called as "AudienceID" then it should be updated on the API Ref. Doc as `audienceID`, not `listID` I believe.

Comment: This saved me, the ID in the URL is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = [
        'email_address' => (isset($email) ? $email : ''),
        'status' => 'subscribed',
        'status_if_new' => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields' => [
            'FNAME' => (isset($firstname) ? $firstname : ''),
            'LNAME' => (isset($lastname) ? $lastname : ''),
            'PHONE' => (isset($phone) ? $phone : ''),
        ],
    ];
    $server = explode('-', $token);
    $url = 'https://'.$server[1].'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$list.'/members/';

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'data_format' => 'body',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'headers' => [

                    'Authorization' => 'apikey '.$token,
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            ],
    'body' => json_encode($data )
    ]
);
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    $return['error'] = "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
    $return['success'] = $response;
}
```

Must be include merge_fields filed into body data...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, that's not why the error was occurring. The error occurred because I had hit `$mail->get('campaign');` INSTEAD of `$mail->get('campaigns');` (note the pluralisation).

MailChimp's generic error message was misleading at the time.